# Efficiently finding all overlapping matches for a regular expression

Tags: java, regex, optimization

This is a followup to [All overlapping substrings matching a java regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11303309/244526).

Is there a way to make this code faster?

```
public static void allMatches(String text, String regex)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j <= text.length(); ++j) {
        String positionSpecificPattern = "((?<=^.{"+i+"})("+regex+")(?=.{"+(text.length() - j)+"}$))";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(positionSpecificPattern).matcher(text);

        if (m.find()) 
        {   
          System.out.println("Match found: \"" + (m.group()) + "\" at position [" + i + ", " + j + ")");
        }   
      }   
    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the other question you mentioned Matcher's `region()` method, but you weren't making full use of it.  What makes it so valuable is that the anchors will match at the region's bounds as if they were the bounds of a standalone string.  That's assuming you've got the `useAnchoringBounds()` option set, but that's the default setting.

```
public static void allMatches(String text, String regex)
{
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
  int end = text.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < end; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= end; ++j) 
    {
      m.region(i, j);

      if (m.find()) 
      {   
        System.out.printf("Match found: \"%s\" at position [%d, %d)%n",
                          m.group(), i, j);
      }   
    }   
  }   
}
```

Given your sample string and regex:

```
allMatches("String t = 04/31 412-555-1235;", "^\\d\\d+$");
```

...I get this output:

```
Match found: "04" at position [11, 13)
Match found: "31" at position [14, 16)
Match found: "41" at position [17, 19)
Match found: "412" at position [17, 20)
Match found: "12" at position [18, 20)
Match found: "55" at position [21, 23)
Match found: "555" at position [21, 24)
Match found: "55" at position [22, 24)
Match found: "12" at position [25, 27)
Match found: "123" at position [25, 28)
Match found: "1235" at position [25, 29)
Match found: "23" at position [26, 28)
Match found: "235" at position [26, 29)
Match found: "35" at position [27, 29)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! Yes, I think that adding the `^` and `$` anchors helps. It turns out that for my purposes I need `useTransparentBounds(true)` as well. Sweet!